# com.google.gwt.user.client.Window How to get Http status code from answer?

Tags: java, gwt

I use `com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.open(String url, String name, String features)` to download file from server.

Every think is ok when the result from server is `200 OK`- I am getting file.

Problem comes when the result from server is different than `200 OK`, for example: `500 Internal Server Error`, or `401 Unauthorised`. Then I am getting ugly Tomcat Error page that contain information about the problem.

I would like to catch every status code different than `200 OK` and display my own information or redirect to f.e. `Login Page`.

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve required functionality, first we need to check for existence of file on server. We can do that by simple head request. Here is a sample code for same

```
XMLHttpRequest req = XMLHttpRequest.create();
req.open("HEAD", fileURL);
req.setOnReadyStateChange(new ReadyStateChangeHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onReadyStateChange(XMLHttpRequest xhr) {

        if (xhr.getReadyState() == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.getStatus() == 200) {
                Window.open(fileURL, winTitle, "");
            } else {
                // TODO handle other status codes
            }
        }
    }
});
req.send();
```